# List GetRelatedFields() returns field ID that doesn't exists in dependant list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column

I have got list item exception. [ArgumentException: Invalid Field Name.]

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid Field Name. {01b89bed-bbe3-4bcb-9b92-c64183ffe135}  /Lists/AcceptanceAgreements]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldById(Guid fieldId, Boolean bThrowException) +27057453
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelatedFieldExtendedData.CalculateTitleAndUrl(SPList relatedList, Guid fieldId, Boolean includeFieldInformation) +119
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelatedFieldExtendedData.GetRelatedFieldData(SPSite currentSite, SPWeb listWeb, SPRelatedField relatedField, Boolean includeFieldInformation) +733
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.BuildExtendedRelatedFieldsData(SPWeb web, List`1 extendedDataList, SPRelatedFieldCollection relatedFields, Boolean bNeverAppendFieldTitle) +678
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetCascadeDeleteWarningMessage(SPRelatedFieldCollection cascadeDeleteRelatedFields, SPWeb web) +130
```

In fact theres is a lookup from AcceptanceAgreements to AcceptancesProtocols (source list). But lookup ID field is [5eeb2b5e-484a-4a56-a397-55f21dc2dbf7] and not [01b89bed-bbe3-4bcb-9b92-c64183ffe135]. The field is not corrupted.

Is there any way to update ID of SPRelatedField? I have got already linked data in that lists.

I tried to use http://splookuplinker.codeplex.com/ but it doesn't work (after operation succeded message).

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for corrupted relations but please backup data before doing it!

```
exec proc_GetRelatedFieldsForList @SiteId='5795D2AB-D171-487A-A6B4-BD93A551773C',@ListId='F88CDA79-9412-46D9-8783-2D5738E8A4EA',@RequestGuid='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

where listId is parent

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[proc_GetRelatedFieldsForList]    Script Date: 2013-03-20 10:01:38 ******/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetRelatedFieldsForList](
    @SiteId uniqueidentifier,
    @ListId uniqueidentifier,
    @RequestGuid uniqueidentifier = NULL OUTPUT)    
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT
        L.tp_WebId,
        L.tp_Id,
        ALR.FieldId,
        ALR.DeleteBehavior 
    FROM 
        TVF_AllLookupRelationships_SiteLookupList(@SiteId, @ListId) AS ALR
    CROSS APPLY
        TVF_Lists_Id(ALR.ListId) AS L



            CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TVF_AllLookupRelationships_SiteLookupList]
            (
                @SiteId uniqueidentifier,
                @LookupListId uniqueidentifier
            )
            RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    AllLookupRelationships WITH (INDEX=AllLookupRelationships_Backward)
                WHERE
                    SiteId = @SiteId AND
                    LookupListId = @LookupListId



CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TVF_AllLookupRelationships_SiteLookupList]
            (
                @SiteId uniqueidentifier,
                @LookupListId uniqueidentifier
            )
            RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    AllLookupRelationships WITH (INDEX=AllLookupRelationships_Backward)
                WHERE
                    SiteId = @SiteId AND
                    LookupListId = @LookupListId
```

Now open AllLookupRelationships table find rows by corrupted field ID and list ID, remove that row.